# Android make xml node for Soap Parameter

Tags: android, soap

a Dot net Webservice is expecting an XML node as a parameter:
The string that it would deserialize to is:

```
"<Service PTA="" QSF="" xmlns="" />";
```

I have floundered around trying to make a serializable class with a public string of:

```
"<Service PTA=\"\" QSF=\"\" xmlns=\"\" />";
```

But I get errors of 'Cannot Serialize' from:
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
What is the best way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a Kludge but it works. using KSOAP2 library.
Adding a xml node to SoapObject request, parameter myParam

```
String xml = "<Service PTA=\"\" QSF=\"\" xmlns=\"\" />";
request.addProperty("myParam>"+xml,"")
```

Not ideal but...